# How to compile apps for multiple versions of ios sdks?

Tags: iphone

I have an app, and I want to compile it for iOS 4.1 iPhone system, but I only have SDK 4.3 on my Mac. Can I compile that for 4.1? How can I configure it? Or so I need to install 4.1 SDK onto my Mac? How can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SDK 4.3, XCode > Select a project > `Project` menu > `Edit Project Settings` > scroll to `iOS Deployment Target` > select a lower version your app supports

Comment: This doesn't ensure that everything works (correctly) on iOS 4.1, though.